# `TreeMap` sort in Alphabetical Order

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary

I was reading about information retrieval and I was trying to replicate the search engine using Java. I created a basic dictionary and a pretty basic CSV file reader. I'd like to sort the terms in alphabetical order.

Here's my code for the `dictionary`:

```
public class Dicionario {
    private final Map<String, Integer> dictionary = new HashMap<>();

    public void makeDictionary(String folderToRead, String[] filesToRead, String regex) {
        final Parser parser = new Parser(regex);

        for (String files : filesToRead) {
            CSVFile.abrirArquivoDeLeitura(folderToRead, files);           

            for (String x : parser.split(CSVFile.readTexto())) {
                String aux = x.trim().toUpperCase();

                if (!dictionary.containsKey(aux))
                    dictionary.put(aux, contador++);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it works fine. First I tried to convert `x` to a `charArray`, sort it and convert it back to a String. No bueno. I also tried to sort the terms using `TreeMap` and `SortedMap` but it changed the results of the CSVFile, leaving it all wrong.

Any tips for me?

Comment: Do you know how a Treemap, Hashmap, SortedMap work internally in Java, because trying to sort a HashMap or Treemap doesn't make sense in the first place? If not then take a look here: https://opensourceforu.com/2015/06/data-structures-made-easy-with-java-collections/

Comment: "I tried to convert x to a charArray, sort it and convert it back to a String" - that would sort the letters in the strings that you've read. TreeMap should work. How does it change the results of the CSV file? (It looks like you're processing each CSV line as a list of separate words - that is what you're intending?)

Comment: I read your question twice, but I haven't been able to figure out what you're trying to achieve, what you expect this code to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: Why do you need to sort keys in the map?